# Turtle layering (probably)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm making a rip-off game that's based on those magic tile games where you tap your finger at one of 4 sections at the bottom to play a note. It is always sideways instead. Right now I"m working on letting the player (the black square on the left) move while the animation for the colored tiles is moving. Right now it is just before the functions that draw the tiles, and I have tried putting the functions within the function that makes the tiles.

```
import turtle as trtl
import random as rand

leader_colors = []
wn = trtl.Screen()

player = trtl.Turtle()
player.speed(150)
player.penup()
player.shape("square")
player.shapesize(7.5)
player.goto(-850,0)
player.speed(50)
def goUp():
    y = player.ycor()
    player.goto(-850, y + 150)
                
def goDown():
    y = player.ycor()
    player.goto(-850, y - 150)

def tileMaker1(many):
    distance = 0
    length = 0
    postion = 1420
    for i in range(many):
         i = trtl.Turtle()
         i.hideturtle()
         i.penup()
         i.pensize(145)
         i.pencolor("white")
         i.shapesize(175)
         i.pensize(145)
         i.penup()
         i.setheading(180)
         i.penup()
         i.shape("square")
         i.shapesize(7.2)
         i.hideturtle()
         i.goto(postion, 0)
         i.showturtle()
         i.penup()
         while distance < 51:
             i.color("blue")
             i.forward(50)
             distance += 1
             length += 50


wn.onkeypress(goUp, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(goUp, "w")
wn.onkeypress(goDown, "Down")
wn.onkeypress(goDown, "s")

tileMaker1(4)
```

Comment: Please repeat on [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). “Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue. We expect you to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: i fixed I put the move function with a listen within the tile maker function